# Leaflet markets dosen't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a problem with marker cluster in leaflet, it's doesn't want to show up on the map.

```
$.getJSON("http://unikabutiker.nu/request.php?f=getAcceptedStores", function (json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.result.length; i++) {
        //markers.addLayer(new L.Marker([json.result[i].lat, json.result[i].lng]));
        var title = "<p class='lead hovertext' style='margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;font-family: sans-serif !important;'><a target='_blank' href='http://unikabutiker.nu/butik/"+ json.result[i].uri +"'>" + json.result[i].title + "</a></p><i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i> " + json.result[i].adress, //value searched
            small = json.result[i].title+". "+json.result[i].adress+", "+json.result[i].city,
        city = json.result[i].city,
            loc = [json.result[i].lat, json.result[i].lng], //position found
            marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng([json.result[i].lat, json.result[i].lng]), {
                                title: small
            }); //se property searched
        marker.bindPopup(title);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }
});
```

You can see the full code and map here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSytj/32/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with some of your code -- it is crashing the script.  `L.control.search` is null.  Commenting that line out, or checking for null:

```
if (L.control.search) {
    L.control.search({  ...
```

Next problem, you get a "cross site scripting" error from the JSFiddle demo.  I assume that this will not be a problem on your own server, so for test purposes I copied a hard-coded the JSON [from the service](http://unikabutiker.nu/request.php?f=getAcceptedStores) into the demo.

With this fix, the marker seems to be working correctly: see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fs62gbw6/7/).  (You do have to zoom out a bit to see the marker.)

Comment: Okey! Thanks McGarnagle, but how to fix the markerclusters?.. It's dosen't shows up..

Comment: Wrong question.. I mean, do you know how to fix so all of the store's shows up from my API? with markercluster

Comment: @User5131231 if your service does not support JSONP (looks like it does not), then you can't get it working from JSFiddle.  It should work once you copy your page up to the same server `unikabutiker.nu` though.

Comment: McGarnagle, It's working now on my site. But the L search control dosen't work... hehe!